# test a function that returns triangle type

Tags: c++, c, testing, integration-testing

I got the following question as part of a screening interview:

Write a function that receives three integer inputs for the lengths of the sides of a triangle and returns one of four values to determine the triangle type (1=scalene, 2=isosceles, 3=equilateral, 4=error). Generate test cases for the function assuming another developer coded the function.

My answer was:

```
#define ERROR 4
#define EQUILATERAL 3
#define ISOSCELES 2
#define SCALENE 1

int detemineTriangle(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if((x<=0) || (y<=0) || (z<=0))
        return ERROR;

    if((x==y) || (x==z) || (y==z))
    {
        if((x==y) && (y==z))
            return EQUILATERAL;
        else
            return ISOSCELES;
    }

    return SCALENE;
}
```

TEST cases:

```
detemineTriangle (0,0,0);   //error
detemineTriangle (2,2,2);   //equilateral
detemineTriangle (3,3,1);   //isosceles
detemineTriangle (1,3,3);   //isosceles
detemineTriangle (3,1,3);   //isosceles
detemineTriangle (1,2,3);   //scalene
detemineTriangle (-1,2,3);  //error  scalene
detemineTriangle (1,-2,3);  //error  scalene
detemineTriangle (1,2,-3);  //error  scalene
detemineTriangle (-2,-2,-2);   //error equilateral
detemineTriangle (-2,5,-2);   //error isosceles
detemineTriangle (-2,-2,5);   //error isosceles
detemineTriangle (5,-2,-2);   //error isosceles


//looking for overflows/underflows
detemineTriangle (INT_MAX,INT_MAX,INT_MAX);
detemineTriangle (INT_MAX,1,1);
detemineTriangle (1,INT_MAX,1);
detemineTriangle (1,1,INT_MAX);
detemineTriangle (-INT_MAX,-INT_MAX,-INT_MAX);
detemineTriangle (-INT_MAX,1,1);
detemineTriangle (1,-INT_MAX,1);
detemineTriangle (1,1,-INT_MAX);

//boundary tests
detemineTriangle(1,1,1)
detemineTriangle(0,0,0)
detemineTriangle(-1,-1,-1)


detemineTriangle (0,10,10);   
detemineTriangle (1,10,10);   
detemineTriangle (-1,10,10); 

detemineTriangle (10,0,10);   
detemineTriangle (10,1,10);   
detemineTriangle (10,-1,10); 

detemineTriangle (10,10,0);   
detemineTriangle (10,10,1);   
detemineTriangle (10,10,-1);   

//checking thread safety
a =detemineTriangle (10,10,10);  
b =detemineTriangle (10,10,10);   
//a==b function does not appear to depend on global or static variables
```

Do you see anything wrong with this answer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me you are not testing if the lengths of the three sides are valid. For instance, you cannot have a triangle with three sides that are `1`, `1` and `1000`. The general rule should be that `longest_size < shortest_side + median_side`.

Comment: I'd say @elnigno has the key point though don't assume that people don't get rejected on the basis of their 'general stuff'.   Recruitment is a strange business.  It's always a good tip to apply "best" coding practice with such answers - such as _always_ bracing if's and having only a single return. You never know if the reviewer has recently been bitten by an unbraced multi-line macro...

Comment: sorting lengths first (so that `x >= y && y >= z` holds) will simplify the checks. E.g. `ERROR` is to be returned iff `z <= 0 || x -y >= z`, `EQUILATERAL` iff `x == z`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also should check side length. As you know the sum length of 2 sides MUST be greater then the length of last side.
so you should also check something like this:

```
if(x+y<=z || x+z<=y || z+y<=x)
    return ERROR;
```

**UPD:** Here is the full solution(including overflow check):

```
inline bool isSidesOverflow(int a, int b)
{
    return b > INT_MAX - a;
}
int detemineTriangle(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if((x<=0) || (y<=0) || (z<=0)) return ERROR;
    // If all sides are equal and greater than 0 - no need to check overflow and validness.
    if(x == y && y == z) return EQUILATERAL;
    //Check overflow now
    if(isSidesOverflow(x,y) || isSidesOverflow(x,z) || isSidesOverflow(y,z)) return ERROR;
    //Check if it's valid triangle
    if(x+y<=z || x+z<=y || z+y<=x) return ERROR;
    if((x==y) || (x==z) || (y==z)) return ISOSCELES;
    return SCALENE;
}
```

(didn't compile, feel free to report errors via comments)

Comment: true, so another test should be added for this.

Comment: it gives false ERRORS for valid triangles like `[INT_MAX-1, INT_MAX-1, INT_MAX-2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>  

#include <iomanip>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

// define the data type "triangletype" with {values}

enum triangleType { scalene, isosceles, equilateral, noTriangle };

// Prototype function which returns the position of triangleType{value}

// Example: Scalene = 0, isosceles = 1, etc. These are zero indexed.

triangleType triangleShape(double a, double b, double c);

// Prototype function which takes the integer value of the 

// triangle type and outputs the name of triangle

string shapeAnswer(int value);

int main() {

    double inputA; 
    double inputB; 
    double inputC;

    cout << "To determine whether a triangle is either:" << endl;
    cout << setw(50) << " - Scalene" << endl; // Unequal in length
    cout << setw(52) << " - Isosceles" << endl; // Two sides equal length
    cout << setw(54) << " - Equilateral" << endl; // All sides equal
    cout << setw(57) << " - Not a triangle" << endl; 
    cout << "Enter side A: ";
    cin >> inputA;
    cout << "Enter side B: ";
    cin >> inputB;
    cout << "Enter side C: ";
    cin >> inputC;
    cout << "The triangle is " << shapeAnswer(triangleShape(inputA, inputB, inputC)) << endl;

}

triangleType triangleShape(double a, double b, double c) {

    triangleType answer;

    if ( c >= (a + b) || b >= (a + c) || a >= (b + c) ) {
        answer = noTriangle;
    }
    else if (a == b && b == c) {
        answer = equilateral;
    }

    // Test the 3 options for Isosceles equality
    else if ( (a == b) && (a != c) || (b == c) && (b != a) || (a == c) && (a != b) ) {
        answer = isosceles;
    }
    else {
        answer = scalene;
    }

    return answer;
}

string shapeAnswer(int value) {

    string answer;

    switch (value) {
    case 0:
        answer = "Scalene";
        break;
    case 1: 
        answer = "Isosceles";
        break;
    case 2:
        answer = "Equilateral";
        break;
    case 3:
        answer = "Not a triangle";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the tests into several test cases testing for different errors. This way you will now not only that the function `determineTriangle` is not correct, but will have some lead on what is wrong with it.

I would say that using a third party library for the testing (for instance CXXTest or google test framework) would be an advantage. Most such frameworks provide different assert functions that you can use for the validations.

Another improvement I can think of is to test each triplet in all its possible permutations - the result of the function should be the same(so maybe write a helper function `testTiplet(int sidea, int sideb, itn sidec, int expectedType))`.

EDIT: my answer only suggests how you can improve your testing part. An important flow of your implementation is mentioned by Sat in his/her answer.

Comment: I'd agree - barring the logic issue that Sat has identified, I'd be concerned that the tests aren't themselves runnable - As Ivaylo says, I'd expect to see each test being run and compared against the expected result, and a report to be output saying how many tests failed.   Also, I'm a bit confused by the "thread safety" tests at the end.

Comment: the testing part is already split in several categories, covering several error classes

Comment: Yes but the outcome of your test is either `all passed` or `something failed`. If you have separate test cases you will be able to say `This case failed`

Answer (score 0):

I'll convert my comment to an answer.

You should also test that the lengths of the three sides are valid. The general rule is that `longest_size < shortest_side + median_side`.

A test for this could be:

```
detemineTriangle(1, 1, 100);
```

Besides this, you can make the testing in general more solid by doing what others have suggested, for instance testing all permutations of arguments (@Ivaylo).

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrestled with this problem.

This is how I solved it.

```
int detemineTriangle(int x, int y, int z)
{
 if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0 )
    return ERROR;
 else
    if (z >= (x + y) || y >= (x + z) || x >= (y + z) )
        return ERROR;
    else if (x == y && y == c)
        return EQUILATERAL;
    else if ( ( (x == y) && (x != z) ) || ( (y == z) && (y != x) ) )
            return ISOSCELES;
    else
            return SCALENE;
}
```

The first if statement qualifies the input to make sure the values are greater than one. The second if statement qualifies if the input makes a valid triangle (two sides added together must be greater than the third side). The third if statement looks for x = y and y = z, which implies x = z. The fourth if statement looks for two sides are equal but the third side isn't. The concluding else statement just returns scalene but you could test for it if you wanted.